# Sum of elements of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this from DB

```
$arr = [
  '0.4%',
  '0.5%',
  '0.6%',
];
```

I would to sum elements. What is the most correct way to do it?

Comment: `array_sum($arr);`

Comment: `echo array_sum($arr);`

Comment: You should really do some research. SO is not here to answer general questions. Google "php sum array elements" and you get https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php, "Returns the sum of values as an integer or float; 0 if the array is empty". Please do the minimum research before asking

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
array_sum($arr);
```

it will automatically convert the values and add them together.